# Modularizing a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app has various sections (subscrition billing, resource booking, resource assigment) and I do not want all sections to be available to all users.

Is there a standard way of making certain views available to particular users only?

Answer (score 1):

Google rails gems for privacy.

Pundit and Cancan are both good. Pundit is more modern.